# Email message recall does it actually work?

Tags: email

I was asked to recall a message I sent out to remove some personal info from it and replace it with a generic made up person as an example.

Does message recall really work?

It's my opinion because you get told a message has been recalled it just causes you to want to find out what was in the original message. All you do is find someone who had already read it.

Can exchange server be adjusted to not tell users when a message is recalled or replaced?

What about bcc, recall doesn't seem to work on these and global emails tend to be the ones you really need to recall.

**EDIT** Also people with smartphones which is common now don't seem to get email retrieved from their phone either

Comment: That's not really about programming though...

Comment: @Kena: absolutely agree and yet it still remains here. But where would it belong? SuperUser?

Comment: I think a breathalyzer built into mail clients would be the superior solution ;)

Comment: It was asked before any of the other sites were up I think, feel free to move it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most cases, it's too late, it just let's me know there was an email you didn't want me to read.

Answer (score 4):

Only works on unopened mail, for users of MS Exchange/Outlook.

read [this blog post and comments](http://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2006/10/11/you-cant-recall-an-email/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of information, if the message is displayed in a preview pane, it is considered read making recalling impossible.

We did some testing just yeasterday and discovered that the recall feature is pretty lame.  As mentioned above it is only recalled if it is unread (or unpreviewed).  In the case where it has been read, the recall only makes the message *MORE* obvious.  Not the desired effect by far.

Answer (score 1):

Only works on unopened mail, local to the server you sent it on.  (as far as I know, I suppose it could work on server farms/clusters too?)

Answer (score 0):

If the recipient is offline and message is not delivered to his PST by the Exchange server, then RECALL works and you get the message accordingly.

Thanks & Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that the Recall This Message Outlook functionality very often does not work.

WinDeveloper just released a server-side solution for Excahnge 2007/2010. It works equally well for both emails addressed to local recipients and for emails sent to foreign recipients. For more details:

WinDeveloper vs Native Exchange Message Recalling
http://www.windeveloper.com/recall/recall_features.htm

Message Recalling Works! Here is how
http://www.windeveloper.com/recall/recall_howitworks.htm